# Is the .NET Core SDK required for runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ubuntu-18.04

I am setting up a Ubuntu machine to deploy a Asp.Net MVC Core app according to the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1910). In it, it asks for the .NET Core SDK to be installed.

If my server is meant to just run the web application, is it necessary to install the SDK?

Also, if my app is developed in .NET Core 3.0 in Visual Studio, is it ok to have it in a .NET Core 3.1 runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime will be enough to run deployed application https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1 
In fact you don't even have to do that. Because you can also Publish self-contained package
https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained
Which will carry all resources needed for runnint your applicaiton on target OS

v3.1 runtime should support your application built in v3.0

Comment: How about if I need the `dotnet-ef` tool? Is the SDK a prerequisite for this tool?

Comment: I don't use that tool much, but I would guess it works the same as other CLI commands like `test`. Additionally https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#other-target-frameworks section says that `dotnet-ef` requires .NET Core runtime. So if you will deliver compiled package then you should be able to apply your migrations in it

Answer (score 0):

From docs;

> Install the SDK (which includes the runtime) if you want to develop
>   .NET Core apps. Or, if you only need to run apps, install the runtime.
>   If you're installing the runtime, we suggest you install the ASP.NET
>   Core runtime, as it includes both .NET Core and ASP.NET Core runtimes.

So you do not have to install SDK if you only need to run apps.

You need to install same runtime version as your project (SDK) version